# How to show only most recent record in relationship in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an animal licensing database, and I'm trying to write a query in a subform that will show me every pet a person has, and the most recent tag they've bought. Right now my query brings back a line for every animal and every year they've had a tag.

```
SELECT tblPets.NAMEOFPET, 
       tblPets.SPECIES, 
       tblePetTags.TagYear, 
       tblePetTags.TagNumber, 
       tblPets.ID, 
       tblPets.PETOWNER, 
       tblPetOwners.ID AS ID_tblPetOwners, 
       tblPetOwners.ID AS ID_tblPetOwners1, 
       tblPets.DESIGNATION 
FROM   tblPetOwners 
       INNER JOIN (tblPets 
                   LEFT JOIN tblePetTags 
                          ON tblPets.[ID] = tblePetTags.[Pet]) 
               ON tblPetOwners.ID = tblPets.PETOWNER 
WHERE  (( ( tblPets.DESIGNATION ) NOT IN ( "Deceased", "Disowned", "Moved" ) ));
```

How do I get my query to *only* show the most recent tag, and not all the tags?

Comment: How do you define *recent*? By `TagYear` or there is any id?

Comment: Should `tblePetTags` be `tblPetTags`? Or is this an intentional inconsistency?

Comment: @forpas the years are simply stored as a 4 digit integer: 2018, 2019, etc. But I'm only interested in seeing the latest year.

Comment: @LeeMac I hadn't noticed that before, but I apparently named the table that unintentionally when I made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the most recent tag per pet by using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to match to the most recent year:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM tblPetOwners INNER JOIN
     (tblPets LEFT JOIN
      tblePetTags 
      ON tblPets.[ID] = tblePetTags.[Pet]
     ) ON tblPetOwners.ID = tblPets.PETOWNER 
WHERE tblPets.DESIGNATION NOT IN ( "Deceased", "Disowned", "Moved" ) AND
      tblePetTags.TagYear = (SELECT MAX(pt2.TagYear)
                             FROM tblePetTags as pt2
                             WHERE pt2.Pet = tblePetTags.Pet
                            );
```

Comment: I need a little help interpreting your answer. What's pt2?

Comment: @Lei-Lonnie . . . It is a table alias -- needed for correlated subqueries such as these.  Normally, MS Access requires `as` for them, so I added in the `as`.

Comment: Awesome! I was getting a syntax error, and the only thing I didn't recognize was the table alias, but figured it out the error, it was just an extra closing bracket. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hmm, I can't edit your answer just to fix a single character. There's a ")" that needs to be taken out.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the correlated subquery suggested by Gordon, you can join an additional table which selects the maximum tag year for each pet, e.g.:

```
select 
    tblpets.nameofpet, 
    tblpets.species, 
    pt.tagyear, 
    pt.tagnumber, 
    tblpets.id, 
    tblpets.petowner, 
    tblpetowners.id as id_tblpetowners, 
    tblpetowners.id as id_tblpetowners1, 
    tblpets.designation 
from   
    tblpetowners inner join 
    (
        tblpets left join 
        (
            (
                select p.pet, max(p.tagyear) as ty
                from tblepettags p
                group by p.pet
            ) mpt 
            left join tblepettags pt on mpt.pet = pt.pet and mpt.ty = pt.tagyear
        )
        on tblpets.id = mpt.pet
    )
    on tblpetowners.id = tblpets.petowner 
where  
    tblpets.designation not in ('Deceased', 'Disowned', 'Moved')
```